# Unable to get correct coefficients for logistic regression in simulated dataset

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I devised this toy example

```r
library(sigmoid)
N <- 10000
age <- runif(N, min=20, max=90)
e <- rnorm(N, 0, 5)
hi <- logistic(-100+2*age+e)
hid <- ifelse(hi>=0.5, T, F)
hid <- as.factor(hid)
df <- data.frame(age=age, hid=hid)
lr <- glm(hid~age, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
s <- summary(lr)
print(s)
```

The variable `hid` contains  4304 FALSE and 5696 TRUE.

I would have expected to get the correct coefficients out of the logistic regression.

Instead I am getting -39.46 for the intercept and 0.79 for the slope. Both with p-values $\approx$ 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're trying to generate data from logistic regression's assumed data generating mechanism, your code does not do that.

Logistic regression's data generating mechanism looks like

$$ \eta = X\beta$$
$$ p = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-\eta}}$$
$$ y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(p, n) $$

What it looks like you're trying to do is create a linear regression in the log odds space, error term included.  That is incorrect.  The error term comes from the binomial likelihood.  To create data properly so that `glm` will estimate the parameters you've specified, you need to do

````
library(sigmoid)
N <- 10000
age <- runif(N, min=20, max=90)
#Changes here
p <- logistic(-100+2*age)
hid <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
# End changes
df <- data.frame(age=age, hid=hid)
lr <- glm(hid~age, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
s <- summary(lr)
print(s)

```
````

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood the DGP of the logistic regression. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask for more information?
$$y \sim Binomial(p, \eta) $$

Is this saying "y is the equivalent of the joint binomial distribution of p and eta?
Or is Binomial(foo, bar) here some function that takes foo and bar as arguments?

Comment: @rorance_ It means that `y` is distributed like a Binomial, with parameters `p` (probability of success of the single experiment) and `n` (number of experiments)