# Observations from logistic regression - coefficients, R

Tags: r, logistic, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

Let's say that I generate observations from logistic regression:

```
n <- 1000 #n. of observations
p <- 5 #n. of covariates
u <- dnorm(runif(n*p, min = 0, max = 1))
x <- matrix(u, nrow = n, byrow = TRUE)
b <- c(2, 1, 2, 3, 6, -3)
prob <- 1/(1 + exp(-b%*%t(cbind(1,x))))
y <- rbinom(n,1,prob)
```

But now if I fit a model:

```
df = data.frame(y, x)
mod <- glm(y ~ . , data = df, family  = "binomial")
coefficients(mod)
```

Coefficients I get are:

```
(Intercept)          X1          X2          X3          X4          X5 
 -7.0004768  16.5132458  -0.6912072  11.7006775   1.5552072   7.0992499
```

It aswell might be a very dumb question showing lack of knowledge, but why are my coefficients returned by `glm` different than these from `b`? A shoot in the dark is that while generating `y` I rely upon probability given by a binomial distribution, so there is a room for uncertanity. Am I right? In the sense that drawing from `binom(4, 0.5)` I could get e.x both `(1,1,0,0)` and `(0,1,0,0)`.

Comment: Running the code a couple of times revelas that the sampling variability of the coefficients is rather large.  Additionally, nearly all the y values are 1, meaning there isn't much to learn here ( there are at times only 3 zero observations). Increasing `n` by a couple orders of magnitude rectifies the problem.  I show how to simulate some responses [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519198/unable-to-get-correct-coefficients-for-logistic-regression-in-simulated-dataset/519215#519215).

Comment: @Demetri Pananos so am I at least partly right? That it is due to the fact that we draw y from Binomial distribution so y is not deterministic and may vary?

Comment: yes, you're right.  Its just that the model data are not the best because the prevalence of the outcome is so high.